# Приложение в трее ОС

Tags: c#

Когда я запустил приложение показалось консольное окно. А как добиться того, что когда есть команда

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("путь к exeшнику");
```

Но чтобы приложение не показывало свое черное окно а работало в трее до того момента, как в этом черном окне появится какая-нибудь строка (Т.е. событие) ,например ?

Comment: откуда там появится строка? Попробуйте подробнее описать задачу..

Comment: Для начала вам стоит выяснить разницу между консольным и оконным приложением.

Comment: @3per например, я прописал код который на словах такой, софт(console application) запущен, и через 5 минут появится на экране строка 123 (как пример)
а пока эта строка НЕ появилась, софт работает но работает он в трее а не на панеле задач, и как только 123 появился софт открывается так, как будто я его запустил прямо из VS 2013

Comment: @VladD консольное -ConsoleApplication
оконное WindowsFormApplication

Answer (score 4):

Добавляете к вашему WindowsForms приложению элемент `NotifyIcon` выставляете там иконку в свойстве `Icon` . В 2 события пропишите:

```
private void Form_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.Hide();
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        private void notifyIcon_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        }
```

Если надо, чтобы приложение не показывалось сразу, то можете в свойствах/инициализации сделать форму невидимой.